# MongoDB Aggregation lookup how often Document is mentioned in other Collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to know how often a Document from Collection A is mentioned in Collection B. I am currently doing this with a $lookup aggregation and the size of the resulting array, but I guess that there is a much nicer way to do that?

Example:
Collection A

```
{ "_id": 1, "name": "User 1" }
{ "_id": 2, "name": "User 2" }
```

Collection B

```
{ "_id": 1, "user": 1, ... }
{ "_id": 2, "user": 1, ... }
{ "_id": 3, "user": 2, ... }
```

Desired result:

```
{ "_id": 1, "name": "User 1", "mentions": 2 }
{ "_id": 2, "name": "User 2", "mentions": 1 }
```

Comment: your approach is good if lookup has limited documents in result..

Comment: @turivishal I alwasy have this question. Most of the stages are expensive like lookup unwind....  which approach is best for large amount of data

Comment: @turivishal can you quantify "limited"?

Comment: @varman depends, 1) this approach is good if collection B has limited documents because *Pipeline stages have a limit of 100 megabytes of RAM. If a stage exceeds this limit, MongoDB will produce an error.* there is a option `allowDiskUse` if memory required for any case, 2) second approach lookup with pipeline, just match document count by $group so this will return required result. 3) add count field in collection A, increment/decrement everytime when add/remove item in collection B, so this is my favourite.. because day by day new data is coming and database increasing size.

Comment: @Fip i don't quantify, depends on result documents total size.